# Gotoif how to set it to allow a 3 or 4 digit response to meet the condition

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, dialplan

Was wondering if anyone can help me currently I only accept 3 cvv numbers and I need to chage this to 4 but I can't find any where online how to put a range in this statement.

```
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${LEN(${vrCC_CCV})}=3]?wait:cc_ccvinv)
```

Visa/Mastercard are fine with 3 didits but American Express requires the four digits on front of the card.

Any assistance would be greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any other language asterisk support AND/OR in expressions.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cmd-gotoif/

```
Example 2


; Are the first three digits of the returned value of ${ENUM} are
;  either SIP or IAX?  If not,  we ignore and pass to normal
;  dialing path at priority 4.
;
exten => _011X.,2,GotoIf($[$["${ENUM:0:3}" = "SIP"] | $["${ENUM:0:3}" = "IAX"]]?3:4)
```

More info about expressions in dialplan

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-expressions/